# ASP.NET MVC5 Google APIs GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync not work in server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client, adsense-api

ASP.NET MVC5 Google APIs GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync AdSense Management API, works locally but not in server,,

```
GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.Folder = "Google.Apis.Auth";

                var credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    new ClientSecrets
                    {
                        ClientId = "XXXX",
                        ClientSecret = "XXXX"
                    },
                    new string[] { AdSenseService.Scope.Adsense },
                    "SampleApp",
                    CancellationToken.None).Result;

                var service = new AdSenseService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                });
```

Any suggestions? I am expecting this to be something really simple that i've missed, and to be a config issue..given that it works locally.

Comment: what error are you getting.   not in server.

Comment: No error appear, just loading,, @DalmTo , i request site by ip address,

Comment: is credentials created ? do you have a service?  The code you have above should work.  What exactly is not working.

Comment: i develope desktop application with same code then i run it on server, it work fine and get Authorization page, but in web, nothing gets, just loading

Comment: yes, i created , http://prnt.sc/a9tc1h  @DaImTo

Comment: you know if its a webpage that you need to create browser credentials and not native client credentials right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you changed your redirect URI to point to your application's auth endpoints.

While testing on your local it was/is most probaly set to something like http://localhost:8080, where as on your server it should be set to something like: http://example.com/oauth2callback

[Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer)

Comment: i created credentials (Web Application) then i set Authorized JavaScript origins to www.___.tk and set Authorized redirect URIs to same domain www.___.tk, it it right?? 
when i set credentials to  (Web Application) i get error in local host _400. That’s an error.

Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

Application: Ads managment_

Comment: at first, i was use credentials (Other client) ,, it work in local ,, but in server just loading @Riaan

Comment: @user1799572, take a look at this tutorial: http://www.oauthforaspnet.com/providers/google/guides/aspnet-mvc5/ and replace all references to http://localhost:portnumber/ in your code on the server to your server URI, example: http://www.nsafadi.tk and then in Google API for WebApps make sure that you set your Authorised Redirect URI to http://www.nsafadi.tk/signin-google
- the comments don't show the www. If your site is accessible with and without the www add both URIs, i.e. www.nsafadi.tk and nasfadi.tk